# UPDATE table with values from table in a different DB

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

Just started using SSMS and having difficulties getting simple SQL commands to work. I have tried using the Import/Export Wizard, but it won't work as the destination table have columns that aren't available in the source column, and those columns don't allow NULL values.

So, I need to write a SQL command where I can specify those column with values that aren't NULL. I believe the correct way to achieve this is to use UPDATE? I have been experimenting with just updating the Primary Key:

```
UPDATE db1.dbo.Customer
SET No_ = v4.No_
FROM db2.dbo.Customer as v4
```

When executing I get the following message:

> (0 row(s) affected)

Comment: What do you mean "specify those column with values that aren't NULL"?

Comment: Hi. I mean that I need to set a value in those columns. They are BOOLEAN so I thought I, eventually, will be able to set it to FALSE through code, as the Wizard won't allow me to do this. I just wanted to explain why the Wizard isn't working for me.

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea for an update from two tables (regardless of database) in SQL Server would be something like this:

```
UPDATE c1
    SET No_ = v4.No_
FROM db1.dbo.Customer c1 JOIN
     db2.dbo.Customer v4
     ON c1.CustomerId = v4.CustomerId;
```

In other words, you need to identify how the rows match between the two tables, and then you can set values in one table to values in the other.

Comment: Thanks again! It seems there are multiple conflicts between these tables as one of them is of a much older version. Might just have to use a .csv file instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE db1.dbo.Customer
SET No_ = c1.No_
FROM db2.dbo.Customer as 'c1'
WHERE
   db1.dbo.Customer.CustomerID = c1.CustomerID
```